Maven Compiler Plugin Issue for Activiti Project in IntelliJ IDEA
I’m working on setting up a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA for Activiti to connect it with Jira. The idea is to move stories along automatically (like from “In Progress” to “Complete”). But before I even import the Activiti GitHub repo, I’m stuck trying to fix this Maven Compiler Plugin issue.
Here’s the error I keep getting:
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.11.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

What I’ve Tried:

Imported the Activiti repo into another project in IntelliJ. That resulted in 70+ errors in the pom.xml file, mostly unresolved Maven plugins and dependencies. So I decided to create a new Maven project from scratch to address this issue first.

SSL Certificate Fix: I added the required Maven repo cert to my JDK - based on the Activiti github instructions (Amazon Corretto 21) using:
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias repo-maven -file path/to/repo-maven-apache-org.pem


The cert seems to have been imported successfully, but the error still shows up.

Settings.xml: I created a custom settings.xml file to bypass SSL issues and added proxy info.

Maven Plugin Versions: I tried different versions of the Maven Compiler Plugin (3.11.0, 3.1.1, etc.), but none worked.

Other Verifications: JDK is set to Java 21, Maven is correctly configured in IntelliJ - until I run mvn clean install


What I’m Stuck On

How do I fix this Maven Compiler Plugin issue? Is it something to do with Activiti or Maven config in IntelliJ?

Do I need to manually download the JAR? If so, where can I find the JAR for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0 and how do I set it up?


here's my pom.xml code - error is  3.11.0 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Activiti_</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Settings.xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>alfresco</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>activitiDefault</id>
                    <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/activiti-snapshots</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ssl-bypass</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure>true</maven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure>
                <maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall>true</maven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>central</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>alfresco</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>ssl-bypass</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>proxy1</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>your.proxy.host</host>
            <port>your_proxy_port</port>
            <username>your_proxy_username</username>
            <password>your_proxy_password</password>
            <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
</settings>

Any help would be awesome

I would suggest to setup a repository manager which handles the different repositories...
